# Updating data from multiple tables based on a row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table called fields that looks like this:

```
 Name          | Table
---------------+----------------
 DateFound     | Table1
 DateUpdate    | Table2
 DateCharge    | Table3
 DateLost      | Table4
 DateDismissed | Table5
```

And what I want to do is change the year for all of those fields in their specified table to 2013. They are all datetime fields in their respective table. So basically, I want to have DateFound to be changed in Table1 from 06/12/2009 16:14:23 to 06/12/2013 16:14:23.

Is there an easy to do this by saying something like:

```
SELECT (SELECT [Name]
          FROM fields)
  FROM (SELECT [Table]
          From fields)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with cursor and dynamic sql, something like this.

```
DECLARE @changeYear datetime
SET @changeYear = '2013-01-01'
DECLARE @tableName varchar(50), @columnName varchar(50)

Declare updateTime_Cursor Cursor FOR
   select name, table from fields

OPEN updateTime_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM updateTime_Cursor
  INTO @columnName, @tableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

      DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
      SELECT @sql = 'Update dbo.'+@tablename+' set '+@columnName+' = DATEADD(yy,  DATEDIFF(yy, '+@columnName+', @changeYear), '+@columnName+')'
      EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@changeYear datetime',changeYear
END

CLOSE updateTime_Cursor
DEALLOCATE updateTime_Cursor
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For the `EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@inputDate datetime',@inputDate` part, how would I specify to change only the year to 2013. All of the dates are different.

Comment: Updated the script, changeyear is set to any year you want to update.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but I think you can run this for each table/field it will do the trick.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET DateFound = DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, DateFound, getdate()), DateFound)
```

Comment: Yes, the only problem is there are a couple hundred of these and I was looking for a way to eliminate me changing values every time.

Comment: You could loop over a list of tables names and field names I would think.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate what dialect of SQL you were using, but you could generate a mysql script to do what you want with the following:

```
select concat('update ',table_name, ' set ', column_name, ' = DATE_FORMAT(',
  column_name,', ''2013-%m-%d %T''', ');')
  from my_table
```

per this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/770b6/2/0)

Comment: Ahh sorry, it's T-SQL, I completely forgot to add it.